# machineKey on Web Farm?

Tags: asp.net

some articles say one thing and some other...
i need to fix things **in my head** :

**1)** if im using **StateServer** in my web farm i need to set the same MachineKey ... **why** ?
is it for the **viewState issue** or for **session issue** ?
the session issue has been **treated** by StateServer Solution...
so i dont understand...
or is it for the viewState ...?

**2)** Is this also apply to Sql session Server ?

**3)** or the MachineKey issue is only for encrypted ViewState  situations ?( the MAC...) ??

**im confused !**

Comment: it's also needed for encrypting/decrypting forms authentication cookies

Comment: but if im not using forms authentications  , is the MachineKey is for the viewstate decode mechanism ? does the sessions in  stateserver are affected by the machineKey ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the web farm servers need to share the same machineKey is that in any scenario that involves encryption/decryption, that is the key they will use.  Because it's a web farm, you won't have any way to know which machine will handle any particular request, so they all have to have the same key so that they can decrypt items that were encrypted by other machines in the farm, and that whatever they encrypt can in turn be decrypted by another machine later.

Comment: this part is understood to me , my question is : if im storing the sessions in a stateServer in a WabFarm ,  are those sessions affected by the machineKey's ? i know that the viewstate CRC check DOES affected by the MachineKey Value.  the quesions is for the StateServerSessions. ( im not using forms authentications. ) thanks.

Comment: Yes, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx all servers in the farm must have the same machineKey when using state server.